# Flatten out a Collection of Collections in order to display on a WPF data grid

Tags: c#, wpf, grid

I am working with stacked headers on a Telerik WPF data grid. The way I was approaching the problem was to create a flattened view of my data. For example.

it would display like the following:

Person A           |   Person B      |  Person C
Month | Earning     Month|Earning      Month|Earning

I have a collection of persons containing their respective lists of months and earning.

Therefore I want to bring each person on the same level or in easier terms, I want to create a single list with all the months and earnings available horizontally.
What would the best way to approach this?

Comment: If you could show us your code representing your collections, that would help.

Answer (score 2):

I am unsure if you want a list that has the people in it multiple times or just the list with the earnings.  I give you a couple solutions based upon the differing requirements and the guesses that I had to make about your class structure.

First assuming you want a list of where each item has a person, the month, and the earnings and you have the structure of a person class with two contained lists (one for earnings and one for months that are synchronized on indexes you can use a variant of the following LINQ query to create the enumeration

```
var flatList = from person in persons
                from month in person.Month.Select((month, index) => new {Month = month, Index = index})
                from amount in person.Amount.Select((amount, index) => new { Amount = amount, Index = index })
                where month.Index == amount.Index
                select new { Name = person.Name, Month = month.Month, Amount = amount.Amount};
```

If instead you wanted just the month and amounts given the same structure you'd write the following:

```
var flatList = from person in persons
                from month in person.Month.Select((month, index) => new {Month = month, Index = index})
                from amount in person.Amount.Select((amount, index) => new { Amount = amount, Index = index })
                where month.Index == amount.Index
                select new { Month = month.Month, Amount = amount.Amount};
```

If instead you had a list of persons that has an earnings object which matches the month and the amount you could write something like this:

```
var flatList = from person in persons
                       from earning in person.Earnings
                       select new { Pers = person.Name, Month = earning.Month, Amount = earning.Amount };
```

Or again if you didn't want the person you'd use:

```
var flatList = from person in persons
                           from earning in person.Earnings
                           select new {Month = earning.Month, Amount = earning.Amount };
```

I hope one of those is what you were looking for, otherwise please clarify your question further because I misunderstood.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, it's difficult to be specific without seeing more of your code. But, in general, flattening collections is the sort of thing that [the SelectMany() LINQ extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx) is made for.